# Body keeps going past full size of webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site for a school project, and for some reason the height of the whole page extends way passed the bottom of the screen. Even setting 100% height makes it go past. Here's the html, but from what I can see in inspect element, its the div container above row1 that leads to the overflow. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```css
 
    html,body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .full-height {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .row1{
      display:flex;
    }

    .column1{
      flex: 15%;
      padding:10px;
    }

    .column2 {
      flex:85%;
      padding:10px;
    }

    .mainContainer {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .bd-placeholder-img {
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
      }
    }
```

```html
 

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UML Tutor for Analysis Work</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
      aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

      <!-- Adding navbar-nav added to right end of navbar -->
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal"
          type="button">Help</button>

        <!-- Help Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="helpModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Help</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Welcome to the <b>UML Tutor for Analysis Work</b> application!</p>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <u>To change pages on the website</u>, you're able to select an individual page from the sidebar or use the <i>Next</i> and <i>Previous</i> buttons to change tabs
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <u>To check your answers for a quiz</u>, select a radio button for each question and press the <i>Check Answers</i> button. The correct answer for each question is highlighted in green, and the rest are red
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <u>To retake a quiz</u>, press the <i>Retake Quiz</i> button that is enabled once you check for answers (see above tip)
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <u>Note:</u> The gray content container scrolls when there is not enough space on the screen for everything
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p><b>Contact us</b> at uml-devs@test.edu for any additional questions.</p>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column" style="max-width: 100%;max-height:100vh;">
    <!-- Custom Row and Column-->
    <div class="row1 flex-fill d-flex">
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical" style="height:100%;">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-intro-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-intro-diagram"
                  role="tab" onclick="loadIntroPage()" aria-controls="nav-intro-diagram"
                  aria-selected="true" value="Introduction">Introduction</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-class-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-class-diagram" role="tab"
                  onclick="loadClassDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-class-diagram" aria-selected="false">Class Diagram</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-use-case-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-use-case-diagram"
                  role="tab" onclick="loadUseCaseDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-use-case-diagram"
                  aria-selected="false">Use-Case Diagram</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-sequence-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sequence-diagram"
                  role="tab" onclick="loadSequenceDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-sequence-diagram"
                  aria-selected="false">Sequence Diagram</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-communication-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-communication-diagram"
                  role="tab" onclick="loadCommunicationDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-communication-diagram"
                  aria-selected="false">Communication Diagram</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-deployment-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-deployment-diagram"
                  role="tab" onclick="loadDeploymentDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-deployment-diagram"
                  aria-selected="false">Deployment Diagram</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-activity-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-activity-diagram"
                  role="tab" onclick="loadActivityDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-activity-diagram"
                  aria-selected="false">Activity Diagram</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="nav-state-diagram-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-state-diagram" role="tab"
                  onclick="loadStateDiagramPage()" aria-controls="nav-state-diagram" aria-selected="false">State Diagram</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column2">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                  <div id="contentContainer">
    
                    <!-- Container for tabs content -->
                    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    
                      <!-- Div containers for each tab -->
                      <div class="tab-pane show active" id="nav-intro-diagram" role="tabpanel"  style="height:60vh;"
                        aria-labelledby="nav-intro-diagram-tab">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-class-diagram" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-class-diagram-tab" style="height:60vh;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-use-case-diagram" role="tabpanel" style="height:60vh;"
                        aria-labelledby="nav-use-case-diagram-tab">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-sequence-diagram" role="tabpanel" style="height:60vh;"
                        aria-labelledby="nav-sequence-diagram-tab">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-communication-diagram" role="tabpanel" style="height:60vh;"
                        aria-labelledby="nav-communication-diagram-tab">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-deployment-diagram" role="tabpanel" style="height:60vh;"
                        aria-labelledby="nav-deployment-diagram-tab">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-activity-diagram" role="tabpanel" style="height:60vh;"
                        aria-labelledby="nav-activity-diagram-tab">
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-state-diagram" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-state-diagram-tab"  style="height:60vh;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                  <button id="prevBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary back">Previous</button>
                  <button id="nextBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary continue">Next</button>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
 <!-- Footer -->
  <!-- Test with: style="position: absolute; width:100%;" and take away fixed-bottom -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark" style="left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#" style="text-align: right;">Test &#169; 2019</a>
  </nav>
  <!-- Footer -->
```

Comment: Prior to this, I did not have the container-fluid, etc., that is in this. I was having an issue of the row not extending to the top of the footer at the bottom, but I then just tried to make the row take up the whole page, but it instead now takes up the whole page PLUS space under it LOL

Comment: Try setting it to an absolute amount of pixels, e.g. 1080 is about the height of a normal full HD screen

Comment: The <a> tags in your `column2` div are all set to an absolute height. Setting a height to 100% is not related to the size of the screen at all, a page will become as high as it needs to fit all the content. You need to shrink the <a> tags in column2 to fit your webpage. Alternatively, you can look into the `overflow` CSS property, but this will probably cause you new problems

Comment: Do you think you could explain what you want to achieve? Do you want fixed header and footer and what's in between to be scrollable?